# Simulating a right-click on a different div

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I right-click on my #texte div, a contextMenu is called.

```
<div id="texte" >
        <p>Bla bla bla</p>
</div>
```

What I want to do is: to simulate the right-click on that area by clicking on another button. For example by clicking this:

```
<div id="otherDiv">
        <form>
            <input type="submit" value="Check" onclick="check()" />
        </form>
</div>
```

Is it possible?

I already tried the trigger fucntion like this:

```
function check() {
            $('#texte').trigger({
                type: 'mousedown',
                which: 3
            });
            //$('#btn-replace-accept_texte').trigger('click');
        }
```

but it doesn't work.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: No it's not the same problem but thanks.

Comment: Not possible with javascript.

Comment: @Orion , why not possible ? jQuery / javascript is powerful

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird You can throw all the javascript you want at the problem, but if user agents don't allow you to do it it is not possible. Not even with 1000000 lines of javascript

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird - +1 for your confidence. but not possible :)

Comment: Ok then if it's not possible I'll try another way! Thank you for your quick answers.

Comment: @PeeHaa not technical true, you could create a menu that appears when you right click that looks like the menu and has javascript functions that do what the menu can do. (You obviously wouldn't want to) When I right click I get Back, Forward, Reload, Save As, Print, Translate, View Source, View Info, Inspect, the majority of which can be simulated one way or another in JS. So the question is, what exactly are you trying to do? Because there is probably a JS way to do it without loading the context menu.

Comment: Technically (as you state) it really is not possible because you cannot recreate all functions provided by it. But you are correct that you can create a fake content menu